# Best way to test for databases/connections

Tags: php, unit-testing

Is there a way to unit-test classes which require database connections? e.g. User-Classes

(DB-)Object mocking didn't quite help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to isolate external dependencies, such as databases, from your code, because it makes it easier to test that code. There are some concrete suggestions for dealing with such problems at [xunitpatterns.com](http://xunitpatterns.com/Database%20Patterns.html)

Comment: That is true, but it's still a good idea to unit test the Data Access components as well, and *that* requires a real database.

Comment: Sure. But you should be able to test this separately from your model layer code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what they do, I suppose you could create a test db and then pass them a test  connection string, or perhaps a pre opened connection with appropriately prepared data.